# wait for all requests to end, promise resolve Nodejs

Tags: node.js, promise, request

`request` module is a pretty popular module in Node.js and I am using it as single pretty simple :

```
request.get("url.com", function (error, response, body) {
    console.log(body);
})
```

Pretty easy to handle with.

What about if I have 10 requests like this, imagine

```
var myReq1 = request.get("url.com", function (error, response, body) {
    console.log(body);
})
var myReq2 = request.get("url.com", function (error, response, body) {
    console.log(body);
})
var myReq3 = request.get("url.com", function (error, response, body) {
    console.log(body);
})
var myReq4 = request.get("url.com", function (error, response, body) {
    console.log(body);
})
.
.
.
```

And I want to have one callback for all when they all actually are done with their own callback function.

```
//body printed
//body printed
//body printed
//body printed
Promise.all([myReq1, myReq2, myReq3, ....]).then((values) => {
  console.log(values); //
});
```

Is this the correct usage with `Promise.all()` to achieve what I want ? Also,1 more question is, with `request` npm, does a promise resolve when the callback function to that specific request starts, or when it ends ?

To make it more clear,

```
request("url", (callback) => {
    //Does the promise resolve here.
    console.log('promise resolved now at start!') 
    ....
    console.log('promise will be resolved now after my logging')
    //which one correct 
})
```

thank you for the answers

Edit:
This is a way with 1 promise i found in another thread, how to do with multiple?

```
function doRequest(url) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    request(url, function (error, res, body) {
      if (!error && res.statusCode === 200) {
        resolve(body);
      } else {
        reject(error);
      }
    });
  });
}

// Usage:
async function main() {
  try {
    let response = await doRequest(url);
    console.log(response); // `response` will be whatever you passed to `resolve()` at the top
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error); // `error` will be whatever you passed to `reject()` at the top
  }
}

main();
```

Comment: Do not use `request`. Even if it was "pretty popular" a few years ago, its API is legacy, it doesn't support promises. Use a more modern library - or just the native `fetch` API!

Comment: Do not write any new code with the `request()` library.  For starters, it doesn't support promises.  And second, it has been [deprecated](https://github.com/request/request#deprecated) and will not be developed with new features going forward.  You can pick another library that already supports promises such as the ones listed [here](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143) - my favorite is `got()`. Or, in the latest versions of nodejs, you can use the built-in `fetch()` [library](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/globals.html).

Comment: In case it is't obvious yet, `Promise.all()` only does something useful when you pass it promises.  Since `request()` does not return a promise on its own, using `Promise.all()` like you show `Promise.all([myReq1, myReq2, myReq3, ....]).then(...)` won't wait for any of the requests.  Use a library that has built-in support for promises and then that will work.

Answer (score 0):

To promise.all with multiple ones, i just needed a counter that counts until all my n number of requests are ended, then resolve.

```
var myCounter = 0;
function doRequest(url) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    request(url, function (error, res, body) {
      if (!error && res.statusCode === 200) {
        myCounter++;
        if(counter==n){resolve(n)};
      } else {
        reject(error);
      }
    });
  });
}

//call doRequest with for loop


// Usage:
async function main() {
  try {
    let response = await doRequest(url);
    console.log(response); // `response` will be whatever you passed to `resolve()` at the top
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error); // `error` will be whatever you passed to `reject()` at the top
  }
}

main();
```

Answer (score -3):

1. Is this the correct usage with `Promise.all()` to achieve what I want ?

   Yes, `Promise.all()` is the correct usage for your requirement. But "request" module won't return any promise. Wrap the response of "request module" with promise and use `Promise.all()`.
   https://www.javascripttutorial.net/es6/javascript-promise-all/
2. Does a promise resolve when the callback function to that specific request starts, or when it ends?

   Callback function will start only when the promise is resolved.
3. This is a way with 1 promise I found in another thread, how to do with multiple?

   For multiple URLs also you can do it in the same way.

Note: Nesting too many callback will lead to “callback hell” or “pyramid of doom.” Which is not recommended. Please use async and await. https://javascript.info/async-await

```js
// Function that do the api calls.
function doRequest(url) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    request(url, function (error, res, body) {
      if (!error && res.statusCode === 200) {
        resolve(body);
      } else {
        reject(error);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

To do the multiple api call, we can call the above `doRequest` function in 2 ways. Based on our use-case.

```js
// Usage: If we want to hit multiple api's one after the another we can follow the below method.
async function main() {
  try {
    let response1 = await doRequest(url1); // url1
    let response2 = await doRequest(url2); // url2
    let response3 = await doRequest(url3); // url3
    console.log("Got response for all API call"); // `response` will be whatever we passed to `resolve()` at the top
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error); // `error` will be whatever you passed to `reject()` at the top
  }
}

main();
```

```
// Usage: If we want to hit multiple api's in parallel and wait till the response to comes back. we can follow the below method.
async function main() {
  let promise1 = doRequest(url1);
  let promise2 = doRequest(url2);
  let promise3 = doRequest(url3);    
  Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then((values) => {
    console.log(values); // resolved values of all promises. This value will be logged only when all the promises are resolved.
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error); // rejected value of the promise.
  });
}
```

Comment: Your wrapping of `fetch()` in another promise is an anti-pattern and, in fact, the reason it's an anti-pattern is perfectly illustrated in how you did it because you don't handle rejections.  You don't need to do the wrapping at all.  `fetch()` already  returns a promise.  You can't just use that directly with `Promise.all()` without wrapping it in another promise.

Comment: Ok, Got it let me remove that example.